# Realtime data analytics using Elastic Stack on data residing in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2

Tags: azure, logstash, elastic-stack, azure-data-lake-gen2

How can we create the real-time data pipeline while data resides on Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2, and the analytics has to be done using Elastic Stack.

What can be the integration tool or technique for the completion of this design?

Comment: This seems lke a word salad question. You should probably think about your requirements and constraints and hire an architect to work this out for you.  Maybe you could also read this: https://www.elastic.co/blog/deploying-elasticsearch-on-microsoft-azure FYI, real time integration on Azure is often done with event hub + stream analytics. Batch data integration is done with Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Nick.McDermaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1690193/nick-mcdermaid) mentioned in the comment that you need to reconsider your design. AFAIK there is no such tool available which can integrate Azure Data Lake Gen2 and Elastic Stack for real time analytics.

Alternatively, the better way to implement your requirement is by using the Azure products designed for real time analytics like [Azure Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-introduction), Azure Synapse Analytics, etc. You can also consider Azure Data Factory for data movement and transformation.

You can check out [this page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/product-categories/analytics/) to know more about all the analytics products available in Azure. Choose the best which suits your requirement and try to implement using official document examples.